# How to remove "[invalid]" items from the Base interpreter selection dropdown, as seen during project creation in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, project, interpreter, new-project

[Screenshot of invalid interpreters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Gpg.png)

I would like to remove these invalid entries, but I can't seem to figure out how. Can someone please guide me? I only want the dropdown to have Python 3.11, and not those other listings.

I searched around a bit online to find someone else with this problem, but I couldn't find anything regarding this specific area of PyCharm.

**EDIT**: The bot thinks I'm not being clear, despite it being unable to see my screenshot

When you create a new project in PyCharm, under the "Base interpreter: " options drop down menu is a list of invalid interpreters from old projects.

I would like these to be removed from the list so that they no longer appear as options.

If they are invalid, I don't want them to appear since they aren't selectable anyways.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a screenshot you can't see, Mr. Bot, that makes it fairly clear.